# Data Binding Custom Class to WPF ComboBox Using DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I know this is basic, but I'm making the jump from vb.net to C#, and the approach I was using in vb.net doesn't seem to be working.
I've created a .dll with a custom class Service.
In my project, I'm populating an ObservableCollection with instances of Service.  I want to display the instances in a combobox using DisplayMemberPath in XAML (WPF).

My instances of Service are populating the ComboBox, but the display for each item is blank; I'm just getting a bunch of blank lines to choose from.

I've tried this with and without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the class itself, although I don't think it should be necessary at this point since I'm still pretty much at square 1.

Here's my code:

```
      <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="TopService"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ServCode}"></ComboBox>
      </Grid>
```

And here's my code behind:

```
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Execute();
    }
    private void Execute()
    {
        SA.franchiseID = "HOL010";
        ObservableCollection<Service> ocService = Service.InitializeServiceList();
        TopService.DataContext = ocService;
    }
}
```

And the code for the class (referenced via .dll)

```
    public class Service : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
    }
    #endregion
    private string servCode;
    public string ServCode
    {
        get { return servCode; }
        set { servCode = value; Notify("ServCode"); }
    }
    public string programCode = "";
    public int roundNum = 0;
    public static ObservableCollection<Service> InitializeServiceList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Service> oc = new ObservableCollection<Service>();
        using (SA s = new SA())
        {
            s.SqlString = @"select 
ps.serv_code
,pc.prgm_code
,ps.round
from prgmserv as ps 
inner join prgmcd as pc on pc.progdefid = ps.progdefid
where pc.available = 1";
            s.reader = s.command.ExecuteReader();
            Service newService;
            while (s.reader.Read())
            {
                newService = new Service();
                newService.servCode = s.reader["serv_code"].ToString();
                newService.programCode = s.reader["prgm_code"].ToString();
                newService.roundNum = Convert.ToInt32(s.reader["round"].ToString());
                oc.Add(newService);
                newService = null;
            }
            return oc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are ever getting `a bunch of blank lines` you may want to look at your Output window, it will usually tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`DisplayMemberPath` is a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx). You don't give it a binding to a property; you just give it a path to a property, which it then looks up by reflection.

Try this:

```
DisplayMemberPath="ServCode"
```

What you were doing would make it use the *value* of `ServCode` as a `DisplayMemberPath`; if ServCode is `12`, it would look for a property named `12` on each item in the combobox -- not your intent, I'm sure.

Comment: Wow.  I assumed I was being tripped up by the switch to C#, but that's not the case.  I'm tempted to thumbs down my own question!  Thanks for your help!  I was on the verge of being discouraged.  I was going for 'understanding the basics' and tripped on my own feet.

Comment: @RockinRaul The learning curve on XAML is pretty steep. There were times in the first couple of years when I used intemperate language.

Answer (score 1):

I have also come to realize while attempting to bind items to an ItemsControl, that the difference between a Field and a Property become very important.  I have been trying to bind to Fields, which does not work.  This is technically not different than in VB.net.  But an implicitly defined Property in VB.net looks very much like a Field in C#.  All that said, I believe I'm ready to go conquer the world now!